# this is a react-typescript project that uses middleware created with Axios to call Api anywhere in react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, typescript-generics, react-typescript

My App component is:

```
import React from "react";
import AllRiders from "./components/AllRiders";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./components/Login";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/allRiders" element={<AllRiders />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my middleware structure index file is :

```
 import { END_POINTS, REQUEST_TYPE } from "../../lib/constants";
import { apiCaller } from "../apiCaller";
import { ILogin as IProps } from "../../components/Login";

export function getLogin(data: IProps) {
  return apiCaller({
    // <--- added return
    method: REQUEST_TYPE.POST,
    url: END_POINTS.GET_LOGIN,
    data: data as IProps,
  });
}

export function getAllRiders() {
  return apiCaller({
    // <--- added return
    method: REQUEST_TYPE.GET,
    url: END_POINTS.ALL_RIDERS,
  });
}
```

Types file for base url is:

```
export const BASE_URL = "https://do-rider.cheetay.pk/alerts_rider?page=1";
```

Api middleware is following:

```
import axios from "axios";
import * as changeCase from "change-case";

interface Params {
  method: string;
  url: string;
  data?: any;
}

export function apiCaller({ method, url, data }: Params) {
  return axios({
    method,
    url,
    data,
    headers: {
      Authorization: "token 6915953acf827475ce611bf14fd9820f51fbd454",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then((data) => data.data.results)
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
}
```

The login component from where I am posting the data is as follows:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { getLogin } from "../middleware/api";
export interface ILogin {
  Login: {
    email: string;
    password: string;
  };
}

const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [login, setLogin] = useState<ILogin["Login"]>({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const handleChange = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>
  ): void => {
    setLogin({
      ...login,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await getLogin(login);
      // console.log(data, "========");
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
  const handleClick = (): void => {
    fetchData();
    navigate("/allRiders");
  };

  console.log(login);
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="email"
        value={login.email}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        name="password"
        value={login.password}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Login</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

now the problem is rising in login component from where I am sendinf my data to getLogin() function in index file. Problem is in fetchData function. and the error says :

```
const login: {
    email: string;
    password: string;
}
Argument of type '{ email: string; password: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ILogin'.
  Property 'Login' is missing in type '{ email: string; password: string; }' but required in type 'ILogin'.ts(2345)
Login.tsx(5, 3): 'Login' is declared here.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the shape of you variable doesn't match what the getLogin function expects.

Use this instead:

```
const login: ILogin = {
  Login: {
    email: 'hello';
    password: 'password';
  };
}
```

Usage:

```
const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [login, setLogin] = useState<ILogin>({
    Login: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
  });
  const handleChange = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>
  ): void => {
    const loginFormPartiallyFilled: ILogin = {
      Login: {
        ...login.Login,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      }
    }
    setLogin(loginFormPartiallyFilled);
  };
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Robert thanks for answering. Can you kindly elaborate this a bit on how to use this type in index file and Login file as well

Comment: Hello! Is it Deliveroo by any chance? I've added the usage in my answer above. Let me know if that helps

Comment: now it is saying this:

Comment: type ILogin = /*unresolved*/ any
Cannot find name 'ILogin'.ts(2304)

Comment: you defined the `ILogin` type in your above snippet? Are you sure you are still declaring that type?